# Return service $http.get response to controller without using $scope

Tags: angularjs

I've been searching around for hours, but I couldn't find a solution. I'm trying to retrieve data from a separate json-file in my AngularJS application. Using the $http I do get the data I want.
However, I want to get specific data from that file at in multiple places. In the service I want to define some functions that controllers can call to retrieve the data (that the service got using $http).
Now the problem is that when I return the all the data to the controller directly, or try to use it later in the service, the assigned variables are undefined.
I try to use *controller-as syntax*, so I do not want to use $scope. However every solution I've found suggests using $scope. This code now logs 
`f {$$state: {...}}`.

*Code of the service:*

```
theApp.service('SettingsService', function($http) {
  this.dataVar = $http.get('../settings.json')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response;
    });
});
```

*Code of the controller:*

```
theApp.controller('SomeController', ['SettingsService', function(SettingsService) {
    console.log(SettingsService.dataVar);
}]);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This `SettingsService.dataVar` will return a Promise.

Comment: I try to use the values that are inside the data that the service gets. I want to use those different values at multiple places in the application.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
https://jsfiddle.net/md954y0a/

what about calling your service at start-up module then passing to submodules  through a service that loads the same instance

html:

```
  <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myctrl">
    {{parent}}
    <div ng-app='myApp1' ng-controller="myctrl1">
    {{myApp1data}}
    </div>  
  </div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp1']).controller('myctrl', ['$scope', 'API',  function($scope, API) {
 $scope.parent = API.getData();

}]).service('API', function($q) {
    var object = null;
  this.getData = function() {
    object = {
      obj1: "DATA1",
      obj2: "DATA2"
    };
    return object;
  }
});


angular.module('myApp1', []).controller('myctrl1', ['$scope', 'API',  function($scope, API) {
  $scope.myApp1data = API.getData().obj1

}]);
```

Comment: This will not give me the possibility to get the different values that are inside the data at multiple places in the application. I want to retrieve the different values using (preferably) get-functions from the service that returns the data needed.

Comment: check my updated answer i think this what you mean by seperating the data, you just need to make it with promises to work